# How to Trigger a Onclick Function on Page at Once

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, console

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PnXdV.png]

Please See the Image First to know what See More Term i'm Talking about!

Can somebody tell and explain what to do if i want to trigger all the See More (Onclick Function at once by running a function via Console in Google Chrome.

For Example :

I want run a Javascript function / Code via Console (Google Chrome Developer's Tool) all the see more on that page at the same time at once!

Do you know which function or code in Javascript do this for me?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
$(".doMoreClass").click();
```

first **$(".doMoreClass")** take all elements with class *doMoreClass* and for each element call click event.

Comment: what is .doMoreClass ? what to replace with it?

Comment: it's class under "see more" link, sorry for confusion.

Comment: when i run this in Console (Google Chrome) , i'm getting this error : 
Error: <![EX[["Tried to get element with id of \"%s\" but it is not present on the page.",".doMoreClass"]]]>

Am i doing it Wrong?

Comment: Here is the HTML Source of See More: 

<a class="see_more_link" onclick="var func = function(e) { e.preventDefault(); }; var parent = Parent.byClass(this, &quot;text_exposed_root&quot;); if (parent &amp;&amp; parent.getAttribute(&quot;id&quot;) == &quot;id_5405928a6fac80448315308&quot;) { CSS.addClass(parent, &quot;text_exposed&quot;); Arbiter.inform(&quot;reflow&quot;); }; func(event); " href="#" data-ft="{&quot;tn&quot;:&quot;e&quot;}" role="button">See More</a>

Comment: load jQuery manual first: 
http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js
(copy content of link to console)

Comment: To see all comment's in all display posts do: $(".UFIPagerLink span").click()

Comment: You can't call **onclick**, on click just bind action to element. When You call `$([selector]).click()` (in this case) jQuery fire all function bind to click action. You can write in console body of function by call `$([selector]).click` http://i.imgur.com/0vvnPi8.jpg, if You wont have 100% sure that the function is fire You can change it and add some console.log/ info/ error

Comment: Did You try **$('.see_more_link').click()**?